# Does this mean I am mining?

Tags: ether

I am consistantly getting work like this

```
  m  19:26:27|ethminer  Got work package: #7ba30d33
  m  19:26:28|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:06
  m  19:26:28|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:06
  m  19:26:29|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:06
  m  19:26:30|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:06
  m  19:26:30|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:06
  m  19:26:
```

The fact that there are all zeroes on these lines makes me believe that I am not mining. However, that may be that the rates that my computer is working at don't show much progress, regardless of the work being done.

**Does this mean I am mining? How does one tell if one is mining or not?**

**EDIT 1**

After installing https://github.com/Atrides/eth-proxy

and connecting to it to `localhost:8080`, I am getting console output many times faster

```
  m  19:59:52|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:02
  m  19:59:52|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:02
  m  19:59:52|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:02
  m  19:59:52|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:02
  m  19:59:53|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:02
  m  19:59:53|ethminer  Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:02
```

but I see far fewer work messages. I am having it send me emails monitoring progress.

Feels like I am mining, but I have no idea. LOL.

**EDIT 2**

I am seeing output on the proxy console:

```
2017-11-11 20:10:12,477 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:10:30,483 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:10:53,393 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:11:16,849 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:11:45,243 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:11:55,169 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:12:05,819 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:12:16,162 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:12:28,789 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:12:30,112 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:12:38,792 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:12:43,076 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:12:49,032 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:12:53,443 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:12:58,643 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:13:09,319 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:13:17,884 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:13:53,282 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:14:04,272 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:14:16,478 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:14:27,672 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:14:31,536 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
2017-11-11 20:14:33,789 INFO proxy # NEW_JOB MAIN_POOL
```

Comment: I'd assume the server started, but isn't mining anything. All of those log entries have a running time of 00:00. That and they all say 0 Mh/s which would indicate the process isn't consuming any processing power. I haven't mined before, but I'd say you need to tinker with your config file.

Comment: Yeah those zeroes feel like they say no mining is going on. I have never done this either, so I cannot tell. It could be a display precision (in other words, it may be doing work at the 7th decimal place).

Comment: I could look at the source, but I can't believe that the program is so cruel as to lead me to believe with all these frantic console output that I am spinning my wheels! If in fact it is a config error, why not validate it and give a warning?

Comment: Glad you think you found the answer. Just a heads up... if things haven't changed since I read into it, the only people who make any money on mining are the owners of huge GPU farms. You are far more likely to spend more money on electricity then you will make mining on a single GPU.

Comment: I am not convinced that mining is only profitable by people with ASIC and FGPA farms. The whole idea of Ether vs other CCs is to make ordinary GPU mining competitive with these massive farms. In any event, I am just doing it to learn and have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found my answer. The problem is my card is too weak to mine with. The `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE: 2147483648` is too small.

```
[idf@localhost build]$ ethminer --list-devices

Listing OpenCL devices.
FORMAT: [platformID] [deviceID] deviceName
[2] [0] Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 BroadWell U-Processor GT2
    CL_DEVICE_TYPE: GPU
    CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE: 4294967296
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE: 2147483648
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: 512
[idf@localhost build]$
```